# WPF DataGrid, cross out the row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, styles

is it possible to cross out some rows in DataGrid?

Comment: what do you mean by "cross out" ? Do you want to strike the text ?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes i have some expanders in cells, not just a plain text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you'll have to re-template DataGridRow for this. Played around with it a bit and got the result seen below. Hopefully this is what you had in mind

[image]

The "cross" Visibility is Binding to a Property called IsCrossed

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                <Path Name="cross" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCrossed}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="cross" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```