# WPF datagrid row strikethrough

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm using WPF Datagrid, I want to strikethrough conditionally, 
just like my below code works for italics, i want to replace italics with strikethrough. Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" doesn't help. I have 5 textcolumns and 1 templatecolumn in the datagrid.

```
    <Style x:Key="abcRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="false" >
                <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used following on textblocks and then applied to individual text columns, this works. and additionally applied opacity = .5 on datagridrow conditionally. Looks Good!

```
   <Style x:Key="RightAlignStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: When I try this I get "'TextBlock' TargetType does not match type of element 'DataGridCell'." exception. Could you please clarify how to modify textdecoration on the DataGridTextColumn

Comment: @conceptacid I got it to work by adding the following to the DataGridTextColumn: `ElementStyle="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}`

Answer (score 5):

See this question: [WPF DataGrid, cross out the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534876/wpf-datagrid-cross-out-the-row)

**Update**
Modified the Style from the link and changed it to strikeout

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                <Path Name="cross" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0.5 L1,0.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="cross" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!--...-->
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried adding an explicit TextDecorationCollection?

Comment: @WholsNinja, nothing to be sorry about. I am sorry to have posted the wrong answer before...